# Why can't I select text (jqgrid input)

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Why can't I select text with the cursor if the input control is inside the jqgrid table?

The problem is relevant only for IE browser 
[image: Example]

I found a solution.

to enable selection for all browsers you need to use this code

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").off("mousedown");
```

To enable for IE browser you need to use this code:

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").off("selectstart");
```

Comment: Please tell us more about the code you use to get here!

Comment: I noticed that can’t select absolutely any text in jqgrid.

I thought I redefined some styles.
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;

But I did not find anything like it. this is strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

to enable selection for all browsers you need to use this code

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").off("mousedown");
```

To enable for IE browser you need to use this code:

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").off("selectstart");
```